# How to assign unique number for sequence data in excel vba and when the data jumps, the unique value changes?

Tags: vba, excel

I am a newbie in Excel VBA Programming. I have a problem which took me more than a week until now to solve it.

If for example I have this data :

```
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
201
202
203
204
560
561
562
```

[my data before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vljC5.png)

which has two characteristics, one has +1 difference, and another one has >1 difference. I want my data to be like this: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOcsq.png)

Could you please help me to find the excel vba code for that? I do really appreciate for your help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Put your range to loop over e.g. A1:A14 in  a variable, have a counter variable that starts at one, loop each cell in your range.rows, if the row number in the range is 1 then make the adjacent column value =1, else if the current cell value - minus the prior is > 1 then increment the counter by one and make the adjacent  column cell value equal to the counter. If not greater than one, do not increment counter and set the adjacent  column cell value equal to the counter. Repeat for next cell in range. That gives you an outline of one way to approach with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a **1** in **B1**.
In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(A2=A1+1,B1,B1+1)
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, Gary! It really works! I actually need it in the form of VBA codes but I can also use this alternatively. Thank you so much! :D

Comment: @KasihDitaningtyas  You can always use *VBA* to put the formulas in column **B**

Answer (score 0):

This simple script will do what you want.

```
Sub Test()
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = UsedRange.Rows.Count
x = 1
  For i = 1 To lastRow Step 1
    If Range("A" & i + 1) - Range("A" & i) = 1 Then
        Range("B" & i).Value = x
    Else
        Range("B" & i).Value = x
        x = x + 1
    End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt reply, Mitch! It works perfectly! I am so glad that finally I can continue my work :D

Comment: Glad I could help ! Would you please choose my answer so I can build my reputation back up. I had to use some for a bounty on a question I had posted for 6 months. Ugh !

Comment: Yes of course, done upvoted. Btw, you seems so expert in writing the codes. I want to know which book did you read to learn about ExcelVBA before. Could you recommend me some name of good books? Since I am really new in this programming skill, I think I should learn more. Thank you again Mitch! :D

Comment: @KasihDitaningtyas I'm certainly no expert. I have not read any books or had any training. I started out by finding code examples that were close to what I needed and just figured out what to change to fix my situation. Since then it's just been a learning experience. I look at the more experienced programmers code and figure out how to streamline my code. Google searches usually find what I need. Also, please select my answer as a solution (a green checkmark will show up). Thanks

Comment: Thanks Mitch. I think I will also do the same to learn more about excel VBA. And btw, I have selected your answer as well :)

Comment: @KasihDitaningtyas well, you did have my answer selected and now the other answer is selected. I'm not sure what happened. Anyhow, good luck on your coding experience.